# When is a block evaluated?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to understand the syntax of the `xml.send` method call in the following example:

```
  builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(opt) do |xml|
    xml.send(rootTag) {
      data.each { |e| generate_xml(e, xml) }
    }
  end
```

The `xml.send` method call seems to be followed by a block. Is the block passed as an argument to the method? Is the block evaluated and the result passed to the method? Is it just run after the method?

Note I am asking this as a general Ruby syntax question, not a Nokigiri specific question (that is just the example).

Comment: Are you asking why the block has no parameters? Like `5.times { puts 'hello'}`?

Comment: Your question is not clear. One the one hand, you seem to be wondering the syntax of block. But on the other, you seem to understand that, and are asking when a block is evaluated. And if you want to ask a general Ruby question, you should not use such specific example, and you should not have tagged it with nokogiri. Please edit the question.

Comment: Not only what @sawa says but also not specifying which method which block is addressing.  A more complex example than necessary to ask the question that may be being asked.  It simply is not clear.

Comment: And what does this have to do with [tag:codeblocks] (the Code::Blocks IDE for C++)?

Comment: There are two blocks in your code. Which one are you talking about specifically? Also, in your last paragraph, you ask about syntax, but in the preceding paragraph, your ask about semantics. Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

The following block is passed to `send` as an argument for the method contained in `rootTag`

```
{
  data.each { |e| generate_xml(e, xml) }
}
```

When a block is passed to a method, the method controls whether/when to evaluate the block using `yield`.